# How to show SKIPPED test case in Extent Reports

Tags: selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am new to Extent Reports and I have linked my testNG classes to this report.

This report shows properly for PASS and FAILED test cases. But for Skipped test cases, it is not showing in extent report.

When I cross verify with testNG report, few test cases got skipped and that is not shown in extent report.

So kindly suggest me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use Listener and below is the code for the same

```
@Override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {

    chiledTest.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName(), ExtentColor.YELLOW));
    chiledTest.log(Status.SKIP, result.getThrowable());
}
```